# how can I allow a method parameter to be null

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, and coming from c#;

in c# to achieve my intended goal I would simply do this

```
public void MyMethod(int? value) {
 if(value is null) {
  // Do something
 } else {
  // Do something else
 }
}
```

how might I achieve this result, if possible in c++?

Comment: Maybe you want `std::optional<int>`

Comment: Or an overload set, `MyMethod()` and `MyMethod(int)`. That would require that you be able to distinguish between the cases at compile time, though.

Comment: Or `const int *value`. But since passing a non-null value requires creating a separate variable, it works better for large structures that you wouldn't create in a single line anyway.

Comment: I just discovered that I can simply request an int without any modifcation and just pass and compare to NULL, but I don't know if there's a reason I should not do that.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't. `NULL` is a [C relic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) from before [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) existed. Comparing an `int` to `NULL` actually just means comparing it to `0`, and I assume you want to treat `0` as the "value is not null" case.

Comment: When you compare an integer to `NULL`, you're actually comparing it against the number zero, not a special "null" value. `std::optional<int>` is the right answer here. [Option types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) are null but better.

Comment: @NathanPierson I indeed do not want to treat 0 as a null value, thank you

Comment: Presumably, you mean `void` rather than `null`. There is no concept of `null` in C++.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that may well be what I meant, I'm used to a different language and trying to figure out how I can apply my existing knowledge and terminology to a different language, I'm used to the concept of `null` for objects with no value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

```
void MyMethod(const std::optional<int>& option) {
 if(option.has_value()) {
  // Do something with the int option.value()
 } else {
  // Do something else with no value.
 }
}
```

`std::nullopt` is what you pass when no value is desired.  `MyMethod(std::nullopt);`

Or if you want to be able to omit the argument entirely and say `MyMethod()` then you can make the argument default to `std::nullopt`.

```
void MyMethod(const std::optional<int>& option = std::nullopt) {
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `void MyMethod(const std::optional<int>& option = {})`

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for overloading:

```
void f() {
    // do something for no argument
}

void f(int i) {
    // do something with I
}
```

Comment: The sensible solution.